# Query Select Item with a value

Tags: javascript, html, dom, queryselector

**GOAL:** Looking to create a vanilla JavaScript reference to an item with a class and a specific value.

**What I'm trying to say in English:** Select the item from a group of matching items where the value == "home".

My attempted selection:

```js
const v = "home";

const pickedSection = document.querySelectorAll('.bonus-section').value == v;

console.log('picked Section: ', pickedSection)
```

HTML

```html
<ul>
   <li class="bonus-section" value="home">home</li>
   <li class="bonus-section" value="auto">auto</li>
   <li class="bonus-section" value="life">life</li>
</ul>
```

(There will only be one returned nodeItem.)

**Current console output:** picked Section: – false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for an [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors). E.g.,

```
.bonus-section[value="home]
```

Demo using a variable below:

```js
const v = "home";

const pickedSection = document.querySelectorAll('.bonus-section[value="' + v + '"]');

console.log('picked Section: ', pickedSection)
```

```html
<ul>
   <li class="bonus-section" value="home">home</li>
   <li class="bonus-section" value="auto">auto</li>
   <li class="bonus-section" value="life">life</li>
</ul>
```

Notice that [`.querySelectoAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) returns a `NodeList`. If you want just one element, you'll have to use an accessor. E.g,. `pickedSection[0]`.

---

If, OTOH, you are looking to find all elements with a given content, then you can't do it using a CSS selector alone. You'll have to iterate on the elements returned by a less strict query and filter them by the `innerHTML` or other:

```js
const v = "home";

const bonusSections = document.querySelectorAll('.bonus-section');
const pickedSection = Array.from(bonusSections).filter((el) => el.innerHTML === v);

console.log('picked Section: ', pickedSection)
```

```html
<ul>
   <li class="bonus-section" value="home">home</li>
   <li class="bonus-section" value="auto">auto</li>
   <li class="bonus-section" value="life">life</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what I was looking for and worked!